# Swipeable tabs into swipeable tabs Android

Tags: android, fragment, swipe

i currently have a layout with 3 Fragments as tabs.
All what i want is another(small) swipeable fragments into one of those parent fragments. Do you have any suggestions what i can use? Or any tutorial, i searched a lot but with no results.

I have this in the "Main layout" with parent fragments:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark"/>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a way to achieve what you want

[image: View Pager Under View Pager]

The above design can be achieved by placing a viewpager with a toolbar and tablayout inside any fragment you want.

Read the tabs section [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for a detailed information on toolbar widget and tablayout.